# Windows 7 operates normally for several minutes after startup, then stalls.

Tags: windows-7, performance, troubleshooting

When I power on my Windows 7 PC it behaves normally for ~5 minutes, and then I can't open any programs. If I opened something quickly (in the time before the stall) I can still use it. When the computer has stalled in this manner, I am also unable to open new tabs in the usual, direct manner, but if I type a URL in webchat, clicking the generated hyperlink still works. Deleting numerous files in one operation is noticeably impacted as well, but there seems to be no problem with larger, individual files.

It was quite the surprise when everything worked perfectly earlier today without stalling.

I have tried removing unnecessary processes that were running in the background, but the affect was hardly noticeable.

I have previously experienced these symptoms before and corrected them by uninstalling Valve Steam whose constant updates appeared to be responsible for the undesirable behavior.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong -- you shouldn't be able to do anything for the first 5 minutes either.

Comment: Do you have an SSD? If so, which one?

Comment: Nope, i have HDD

Answer (score 1):

Do: 
Start >> Run >> Type: `MSCONFIG`

select the start-up tab and see whats booting-up and disable as much as possible
besides you're firewall/antivirus suite.

Could be a virus, or too many programmes booting causing you're computer to use page file to stay stable.

Like what bosco above said it could be a number of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid without further information I can't be of much help. I can, however, point you to some other questions whose authors were experiencing exceptionally similar issues, wherein many troubleshooting steps are listed and various solutions are presented:

- [My Computer hangs for a few minutes just after startup, and then is fine](https://superuser.com/questions/130189/my-computer-hangs-for-a-few-minutes-just-after-startup-and-then-is-fine?rq=1)
- [Slow startup on Windows 7 Home Premium laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/216207/slow-startup-on-windows-7-home-premium-laptop)
- [Computer slow or is just me?](https://superuser.com/questions/429214/computer-slow-or-is-it-just-me)
- [windows 7 fast in safe mode but extremely slow in normal mode](https://superuser.com/questions/427019/windows-7-fast-in-safe-mode-but-extremely-slow-in-normal-mode)
- [How can I time my startups and see what processes are taking the longest?](https://superuser.com/questions/168600/how-can-i-time-my-startups-and-see-what-processes-are-taking-the-longest)
- [How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7)

Cheers and good luck! Let me know if I can be of further assistance.

Comment: I have the exact oposite of these problems, everything works well only for a while after startup.

Comment: @gabberswag Nonetheless, these posts contain many troubleshooting steps that are still relevant to your situation. For instance, opening up the **Resource Monitor** will no doubt give you great insight into what bottlenecks your system might be facing.

Comment: CPU usage is close to 1% without chrome and resource monitor, but that didnt help much.

Comment: CPU isn't all that matters here. You should also grab metrics for "Highest Active Time" for disk activity, check to make sure your "Disk I/O" isn't maxed, Physical Memory available, etc.

Comment: Actually, i noticed that in normal mode after few minutes memory usage is ~600MB higher than 800 in safe mode.

Comment: You're probably normal mode, unless you restarted and explicitly told Windows to boot into [Safe Mode](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/safe-mode-windows-7.htm) (i.e. you were given a choice between and chose one of "Safe Mode", "Safe Mode with Networking", or "Safe Mode with Command Line"). Typically while in safe mode your wallpaper is replaced and the corners indicate "Safe Mode".

Comment: It's normal for your system to use more resources in normal mode than safe mode as non-critical processes and services are not started. What is of particular interest regarding safe mode is whether or not your computer still stalls when you are booted into it (as we already know it stalls in normal mode).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ve7CddJ.png 
Well, i dont know if its normal but that peak is the moment i cant open anything anymore. Even if i try to, memory usage isnt growing. Its almost straight line after that. And it wasnt ~600MB, my bad, it was ~1GB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restoring to an earlier point to see if that fixes it?

If that doesn't work, check your processor temp. This problem can happen if your processor is overheating.

[coretemp32.zip](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/CoreTemp32.zip)

[coretemp64.zip](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/CoreTemp64.zip)

Comment: Im sure its not about temperature, i cleaned my pc and when this problem showed up, processor was cold.

Comment: @gabberswag - Verify the temperature.  If the heatsink isn't properly installed it could explain this behavior.

Comment: It might not be a temperature issue, but you should check it so that you can rule it out. Also, the processor can overheat within just a few seconds after starting up from a "cold" state.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/LoP6fZH.png
I dont think thats the problem?

Comment: have you launched reliability monitor?